# reducing space before and after sub-headings

Tags: spacing

How can I reduce the space between \subsection and its following text, and also with \subsubsection. Currently it has a 2-line space above, and a 3-line space before and after the two headers. I am using `\documentclass{scrreprt}` and `\usepackage{savetrees}`.

[image: some of the \subsubsection]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 
\usepackage{savetrees}
\usepackage{lipsum}

 \begin{document}

 \subsection{Indications}

 \subsubsection{Prices}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scrreport` document class defines the macros `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` by invoking the LaTeX kernel command `\@startsection` with the following settings:

```
\newcommand\subsection{%
  \@startsection{subsection}{\subsectionnumdepth}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@subsection
  }%
}
\newcommand\subsubsection{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@subsubsection
  }%
}
```

The fifth argument of `\@startsection` -- in both cases, `{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}` -- controls the amount of vertical space *below* the sectioning header. To reduce this amount by a half, i.e., to `{0.75ex \@plus .1ex}`, you could load the `etoolbox` package and use its `\patchcmd` macro as follows (insert the code in the preamble):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\subsection}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{0.75ex \@plus 0.1ex}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsubsection}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{0.75ex \@plus 0.1ex}{}{}
\makeatother
```

If you also need to reduce the space *above* subsection and subsection headers, you can do so by using `\patchcmd` to alter the *fourth* argument of the respective `\@startsection` commands.

A final observation: Since you're also using the `savetrees` package, you need to load that package with option `sections=normal` in order to let the code above have an effect. (Without this option, the `savetrees` package invokes the `titlesec` package to modify the spacing around sectioning headers, leading the code above to do nothing.)

Comment: Thanks @Mico. With your code in place I am consistently getting errors for each and every \subsection and \subsubsection like this - [12]
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   !
l.250 \subsection*{Adverse Reactions}
                                     
?

Comment: Sorry for the noise, uncommented left-over code was stopping it from running properly. It is now running with zero problems at all. Thanks.